# How to use AutoLayout in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I am creating view without using storyboard or XIB. I am also using MvvmCross in project and binding controls like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using CoreFoundation;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;

namespace Mobile.iOS.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Home screen of iPhone
    /// </summary>
    [Register("HomeView")]
    public class HomeView : MvxViewController
    {   
        /// <summary>
        /// Method to load the view
        /// </summary>
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            View = new UIView() { BackgroundColor = UIColor.White };
            this.Title = "Home";
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var lblHome = new UILabel(new RectangleF(80, 100, 300, 40));
            lblHome.TextColor = UIColor.Green;
            Add(lblHome);

            var btnSignIn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            btnSignIn.SetTitle("Move to Login Screen", UIControlState.Normal);
            btnSignIn.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 200, 300, 40);
            Add(btnSignIn);

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
            set.Bind(lblHome).To(vm => vm.HomeTitle);
            set.Bind(btnSignIn).To(vm => vm.LogIn);
            set.Apply();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view
        }     
    }
}
```

I want to use AutoLayout to design my view. So that my views looks fine and similar in all iPhone device (4s, 5, 5s, 6) and views (portrait or landscape).

Comment: Have you looked at using https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

Comment: No, I don't look at this. I am looking now and let you know how helpful this for this purpose.

Comment: You are asking for a tutorial on how to use AutoLayout. This does not fit very well into the QA style of StackOverflow. I have marked it for closing. If you want it to be kept open, add the attempts to specific layout constraints you have tried and what failed etc.

Comment: I was just know that by using auto layout we can design our view for all iPhone device. I just want to know that how can be used auto layout with MvvmCross. So I put this question. I was not know how to use that so I was not try and not facing any kind of error. So please open this , it will be helpful for others who are design view by code with MvvmCross

Comment: hmmm though this was answered? If you need more information on Auto Layout I would check out the links I posted or look for another tutorial. If your question has been answered by the two below then mark one as accepted. If not then we need more information as to what you are trying to achieve and like Cheesebaron said it would be good to see what you have tried. As a side note AutoLayout is not affected by MvvmCross and vice versa.

Comment: I am using FluentLayout , I need to use two control on same top adjacent to each other. I write:

           lblShowPassword.Below( txtfldPwd, 2 * lrMargin ),
          lblShowPassword.WithSameLeft( segmentControl ),
          lblShowPassword.ToLeftOf( switchShowPassword, 4 *lrMargin),
          lblShowPassword.Height().GreaterThanOrEqualTo( 2 * lrMargin ),

           switchShowPassword.WithSameTop( lblShowPassword ),
           switchShowPassword.AtRightOf( lblShowPassword, 4 * lrMargin ),

But both controls are overlapped to each other on same position. 
What I missing in this ?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing excatly how you want the label and button to react to the size changes. I came up with this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using CoreFoundation;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;

namespace Mobile.iOS.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Home screen of iPhone
    /// </summary>
    [Register("HomeView")]
    public class HomeView : MvxViewController
    {  
        UILabel lblHome;
        UIButton btnSignIn;

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            View = new UIView() { BackgroundColor = UIColor.White};
            this.Title = "Home";
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            //          var lblHome = new UILabel( new RectangleF(80,100,300,40) );          
            lblHome = new UILabel();
            lblHome.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false; // need this for autolayout
            lblHome.Text = "HOME LABEL";
            lblHome.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            lblHome.TextColor = UIColor.Green;
            lblHome.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan;
            Add( lblHome );

            btnSignIn = new UIButton( UIButtonType.RoundedRect );
            btnSignIn.SetTitle( "Move to Login Screen", UIControlState.Normal );

            btnSignIn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Magenta;
            //          btnSignIn.Frame = new RectangleF( 10, 200, 300, 40 );
            btnSignIn.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;  // need this for autolayout
            Add( btnSignIn );

            SetupAutoLayoutConstraints ();

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
            set.Bind( lblHome ).To( vm => vm.HomeTitle );
            set.Bind( btnSignIn ).To( vm => vm.LogIn );
            set.Apply();
        }



private void SetupAutoLayoutConstraints()
    {
        View.AddConstraints (new [] {
            // makes the width of lblHome the same width as the View and then -20 from this
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(lblHome, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, -20),
            // makes the height of lblHome 40
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(lblHome, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 40),
            // makes the Top of lblHome 100 from the top of the view
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(lblHome, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 100),
            // centers lblHome in View along the x-axis
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(lblHome, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0)
        });


        View.AddConstraints (new [] {
            // makes the width of btnSignIn the same width as the lblHome
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(btnSignIn, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, lblHome, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0),
            // makes the height of btnSignIn the same height as the lblHome
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(btnSignIn, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, lblHome, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 1, 0),
            // makes the Top of btnSignIn 60 from the bottom of lblHome
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(btnSignIn, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, lblHome, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 60),
            // centers btnSignIn in View along the x-axis
            NSLayoutConstraint.Create(btnSignIn, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1, 0)
        });
    }
    }
}
```

When using autolayout you dont want to set and frames but rather add the views then set up their constraints like in the `SetupAutoLayoutConstraints` method.

Helpful links on auto layout:

[Raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[Other Tutorial](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it, but it not works, even for a single device, portrait and landscape view also not adjust, it makes difference. Have you miss something in this ?

Comment: Would you be able to update your question with the whole of your class?

Comment: hey I have updated my answer, let me know if its suits. I added in background colors to show where the views are but you can remove these, also I centered the text in the home label.

Comment: Great..!!, its working now. I checked it in all device and in both portrait and landscape views. Its work nice..!! Thanks Iain Smith. :)

Comment: Can you also suggest me any article for more understanding about Auto Layout. I want to more understand what magic you do in "SetupAutoLayoutConstraints" method.

Comment: Added the too links I used when starting, it might be in swift or objective-c but you are mainly wanting to know about the relationships with the constraints.

Comment: Also added in comments on the constraints too.

Comment: Yes, this works for me. But , I has replace this by using Cirrious.FluentLayout.Touch

Comment: I just wanted to say that after many days of suffering, your post finally fully clarified how AutoLayout works programatically. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, Autolayout can be a pain!